# Gradient Descent for Markov Dynamics

Tags: matrix-analysis, differential-calculus

The closed-loop dynamics of a linear optimal controller are simple but have interesting properties. From a starting state $\mathbf{v}(0)$ the dynamic can be iterated to reach a final state $\mathbf{v}(N)$ as in

$$
\mathbf{v}(N) = (A - BC)^N\mathbf{v}(0).
$$

I would like to optimize the transition parameter matrix $A$ through gradient descent with rate $\eta$:

$$
A' = A - \eta\frac{df}{dA}
$$

with loss function $f$ is the error between a generic resultant state $(A - BC)^N\mathbf{v}$ and a target state $\mathbf{w}$. $\newcommand\norm[1]{\lVert#1\rVert}$I'm struggling to find the derivative $\frac{\partial{f(A)}}{\partial{A}}$ of this scalar loss function (L2 norm)
$$
f(A) = \norm{(A - BC)^N\mathbf{v} - \mathbf{w}}_2^2
$$
where $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$, $B\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$,  $C\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$, and $\mathbf{v},\mathbf{w}\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$.

Using chain rule, I can write this as
$$
\frac{\partial{f(X)}}{\partial{X}} = 
\frac{\partial{f(X)}}{\partial{g(X)}}
\frac{\partial{g(X)}}{\partial{h(X)}}
\frac{\partial{h(X)}}{\partial{X}}
$$
where
\begin{align*}
f(X) & {}= g(h(X)) \\
g(X) & {}= \norm{X\mathbf{v} - \mathbf{w}}_2^2 \\
h(X) & {}= (X-BC)^N.
\end{align*}

The problem is, I'm not clear on how to take these these intermediate derivatives.

Comment: You have $f(X) = g(h(X))$, and then you define $g(X)$ and $q(X)$.  Presumably $q$ is meant to be $h$?

Comment: fixed, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $A$ only appears in the combination $M=A-BC$, so the derivative with respect to $A$ equals the derivative with respect to $M$; The function $f(A)$ is given by
$$f(A)=||(A - BC)^Nv - w||_2^2=(M^Nv)^T M^Nv+w^Tw-2w^TM^Nv.$$
For a simple case, let me first consider a scalar perturbation, $f(A+\epsilon I)=f(A)+\epsilon df/dA$, with derivative
$$\frac{df}{dA} =2N(M^Nv-w)^TM^{N-1}v.$$

Next consider the derivative with respect to a given matrix element $A_{ij}$ of $A$. The expressions are more lengthy, basically each matrix $M$ gives a separate term so we have a sum $\sum_{k=1}^N$ instead of the factor $N$:
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial A_{ij}}= 2\sum_{k=1}^N\sum_{p,q=1}^n (M^Nv-w)_q (M^{k-1})_{qi} (M^{N-k})_{jp} v_p.$$
Note that the scalar perturbation is the trace of the matrix of elementwise perturbations, $df/dA=\sum_{i=1}^n \partial f/\partial A_{ii}$.

Comment: Thanks Professor Beenakker. I'm a little confused why the gradient here is scalar, when I expected a gradient in terms of the elements of A? That is, I expect the gradient here to tell me the change in f(A) with respect to each element of A. What am I missing?

Comment: Yes, this is for a scalar perturbation, $f(A+\epsilon I)=f(A)+\epsilon \partial f/\partial A$. The expressions for the derivative with respect to a given matrix element of A are more lengthy, I will write them down tomorrow.

Comment: I see, this makes sense. Thank you. This [calculator](http://www.matrixcalculus.org/) is interesting-- I'm not able to reproduce the scalar perturbation but it produces a nice-looking solution for a general derivative with input `norm2((A-B*C).^N*v-w)^2`. I'm curious to see if the answer there is interpretable to you. It's difficult for me to form an intuition about it unfortunately.

Comment: my answer for the elementwise derivative is not what I seem to get from this online calculator, which gives (if I understand the syntax correctly) that $\partial f/\partial A_{ij}= 2N(M^Nv-w)_i (M^{N-1})_{ij} v_j.$ I don't understand why. This latter result also does not satisfy the relation that the scalar derivative is the trace of the matrix of elementwise derivatives. Quite possibly I am missing something essential.

Comment: Thanks Professor! I've numerically confirmed the online calculator and your scalar perturbation results. I discovered the online calculator is performing elementwise exponentiation, explaining the discrepancy. I'm working now to convert your elementwise derivative to a matrix expression for computation. It seems a tensor product might help. 

Context: I'm working on gradient descent for Markov dynamical systems. If you have any references or suggestions to help me proceed with similar calculations, I would be very grateful. I'm hoping to compute second-order (Newton's method) as well.

Comment: For your full solution, I think we can write this in matrix form where $\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{A_{ij}}}=2\sum_{k=1}^N{x_k^Ty_k}$ and $x_k=(M^{k-1})^T(M^Nv-w)$ and $y_k=M^{N-k}v$. This makes the connection to the scalar case a little clearer perhaps. Both rank-1, and it looks like in the latter case the derivative finds interactions between different time steps of the Markov sequence, through $M^{k-1}M^{N-k}$...? So the full solution (but do confirm) is: $2\sum_{k=1}^N{(M^Nv-w)^TM^{k-1}M^{N-k}v}$.

Comment: yes, that is correct, with the understanding that there is no multiplication of the matrices $M^{k-1}$ and $M^{N-k}$ (that is why I prefer to write the indices out explicitly, otherwise the expression seems ambiquous)

Comment: Right, thank you! If you have any favorite references for matrix calculus, I would love to know.